# Where to put my own libraries?

Tags: directory, libraries

I have my own header files and libraries, which I don't want to copy for every new project, since this makes fixing bugs or adding new features to the library difficult. So I want to put them in a 'public' directory like `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include` and their library counterparts, but I don't know where I am messing with the system! I could create my own directory and specify it with every compile, but that's cumbersome. Where can I put those files? I found a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17545/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-library-files) about that, where the answer is `/usr/local/include`, but I read somewhere that it is used for the package manager, is that true?

Answer (score 1):

If the applications are to be used by all the user in the system, the `/usr/local` tree is the ideal place; no package should put files there (it is for software you are compiling yourself), but the directory `/usr/local/lib` is in the default path for the dinamyc loader. (see `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`).

I normally even move the `/usr/local` tree under `/home` (just by moving the directory `/usr/local` to `/home/local`, and then symlinking `/usr/local -> /home/local`) so that it survives a complete reinstall(1).

If the applications are just for your user, I normally create `$HOME/lib`, `$HOME/include` and then play with environment variables or compiler flags to point to them.

---

*Footnotes*

(1) I normally install `/` and `/home` on separate partitions, but this is a very personal choice.

Comment: So I move "myheader.h" simply to /usr/local/ and "libmylib.a" to /usr/library/. Then I include with `#include <myheader.h>` and link the library with the compiler option -lmylib, right?

Comment: I ment /usr/include, of course. But why not put it into /usr/local/include? What's the difference?

Comment: No. The `/usr/local` is the *tree*. Includes go to `/usr/local/includes`, library to `/usr/local/lib`, configuration files to `/usr/local/etc`...

Answer (score 0):

I have created the convention of creating a new local directory in /usr/local. so it's /usr/local/local/lib for me.  This allows other developers to release their stuff into /usr/local and you then don't get any file name clashes.  If you then want to publish and move your stuff to /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include you may need to make a name change across all your source and make files, which will be a pain, but sed will help if you take care and proceed with caution.  When you have libraries in /usr/local/lib or any where that is non-standard you have to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so executing programs know where to look to link themselves.